# <img src=""> not working when send by PHP mail()

Tags: php, image, debugging, html-email

I am sending a simple mail with mail() with an IMG tag, the recived email shows IMG tag but it doesnt display src="" attribute.

Comment: We need more details, please show the source code of the email you send as well as the SMTP header fields.

Comment: Got it, was a silly mistake, Gmail's option "DISPLAY IMAGES".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Got it, was a silly mistake, Gmail's option "DISPLAY IMAGES".